# Microsoft Excel run-time error 438 when using macro to sort a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

So, I have a macro that I use on one PC to sort a range of cells in Excel 2016 by the numerical values in one column of cells within that range:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
    "H12:H32"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A12:J32")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

This has worked fine on one PC but on my new laptop, when I try to run the macro, I get error 438, which is the

> object doesn't support this property or method

error. I have no clue how to fix this because I have the coding skill of a baboon and hacked this macro together off of something I found on google two years ago, so please use simple words when explaining where I messed everything up.

Specifically, when I hit the debug button, the little yellow idiot arrow is pointing at the part that says x1SortTextAsNumbers, if that's helpful.

Comment: Which line generates this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and fixed your error. I change `Sort.SortFields.Add2` to `Sort.SortFields.Add` and it worked.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "H12:H32"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
```

Try if this works for you.

Comment: Yep, this fixed it. Turns out my, uh, perfectly legal copy of office on my laptop is just old enough that SortFields.Add2 isn't supported.